# Get total Input stock value in warehouse via many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

There is a `Product` Model that has a **ManyToMany** relation to another model named `Warehouse`.

`Product` model:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'product_id';
    protected $fillable = ['code', 'title', 'price'];

    public function warehouses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Warehouse::class,
                         'product_warehouse', 'product_id', 'warehouse_id')
                    ->withPivot('stock')
                    ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

`Warehouse` model :

```
class Warehouse extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'warehouse_id';

    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 
                        'product_warehouse', 'product_id', 'warehouse_id')
                    ->withPivot('stock')
                    ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

In the pivot table there is a `stock` column that holds stock of a product in a specific warehouse.

Suppose `product_warehouse` table is like :

```
+------------+--------------+-------+
| product_id | warehouse_id | stock |
+------------+--------------+-------+
|          1 |            1 |    10 |
|          2 |            1 |    30 |
|          1 |            2 |    15 |
+------------+--------------+-------+
```

And `products` table is :

```
+------------+-------+
| product_id | price |
+------------+-------+
| 1          | 20000 |
| 2          | 50000 |
+------------+-------+
```

As you can see each product has a `price` column.

For example in warehouse **#1**, beacause we have **20** of the product **#1** with price **20000** (`20 * 20000 = 400000`) and **30** of product **#2** with price **50000** (`30 * 50000 = 1500000`) , as a result warehouse **#1** has (`400000 + 1500000 = 1900000`) input value stock.

Now suppose we have selected a warehouse and want to get total price of input stock. I know that should first get stocks of each products from `product_warehouse` table and then multiply each them in it's `price` and sum total of them But I do not know how can I write it with eloquent relations laravel.

Comment: I think `$warehouse->product->pivot->stock` or something in that nature. (Where `$warehouse` is instance of Warehouse loaded with product relationship). You can always run tinker and play with eloquent there... (artisan tinker) `$w = resolve(App\Warehouse::class); $w->load('products');...`